# Game Lag - Obstacle Creation Error

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem with this simple game where the obstacle creation is making the game lag terribly, as well as become a red streak instead of a single cube:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

white = (225, 225, 225)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (225,0,0)
blue = (0,0,225)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
millisToEvent = random.randint(500, 2001)
millisFromEvent = 0

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Jumpy!")

exitGame = False

touchingGround = False

Y = 180;
YV = 1;
obX = 300

grounded = True

fps = 200

def createObstacle(obX):
    obX = 300
    pygame.time.wait(random.randrange(200, 1600))
    while obX > -19:
        obX -= 0.1
        gameDisplay.fill(red, rect = [obX, 180, 20, 20])
        pygame.display.update()

while not exitGame:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exitGame = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if grounded == True:
                    YV -= 3
                    Y += YV

    if Y <= 180:
        YV += 0.1
        Y += YV
        grounded = False
    else:
        YV = -0.1
        grounded = True

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    gameDisplay.fill(blue, rect = [50, Y, 20, 20])
    gameDisplay.fill(black, rect = [0, 200, 300, 100])
    pygame.display.update()

    millisFromEvent += clock.tick(fps)

    if millisFromEvent > millisToEvent:
        createObstacle(obX)
        millisToEvent = random.randint(500, 2001)
        millisFromEvent = 0

    createObstacle(obX)

    clock.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: You are putting a wait inside your create obstacle function, which is blocking your main loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear that you seem to think you have multiple threads going on, but when you call createObstacle, it won't return control to the main loop until it has finished running. You need to paint the box at the right position every frame, not at all the positions every frame.

To fix the lag, remove this line `pygame.time.wait(random.randrange(200, 1600))`, set fps to something reasonable instead, like 60 instead of 200. Also, don't call display.update for the whole screen more than once per frame. You can call it once before `clock.tick(fps)`. This also goes for clock.tick, only once per loop.

It's probably a good idea to follow a tutorial and examine (play and modify!) the included examples.